# Open the Firefox browser console programatically from within an extension using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have tried attaching `toJavaScriptConsole()` to a button but this is not working (undefined reference error)

How can I program an XUL button to open the firefox browser console so we can see logs from the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a scope where HUDService is not available then to get access to it do the following:

```
var devtools = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/Loader.jsm", {}).devtools;
var HUDService = devtools.require("devtools/webconsole/hudservice");
```

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet will work.

```js
if(HUDService.getBrowserConsole()) // is it already open?
  HUDService.getBrowserConsole().chromeWindow.focus();
else
  HUDService.toggleBrowserConsole();
```